# Is there a way to test combining both TestServer and moq Mock to replace methods in classes in ConfigureTestServices?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, moq

I am able to do integration tests using [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2), and I can manually mock methods in any DI injected class by replacing in `ConfigureTestServices` the class by a mocking one as follows :

```
var webHostBuilder =
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("Testing")
        .UseContentRoot(projectDir)
        .ConfigureTestServices(s =>
        {
            s.TryAddTransient(IMyClass, MyMockMyClass);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Where `MyMockMyClass` is a remplacement of `MyClass`, with the purpose of replacing a method (eg: `Method1`).

Is there an option to use a moq `Mock.Of<MyClass>` to quickly replace on the fly my `Method1`, without the need to create a new class `MyMockMyClass`? Something like :

```
var mymock = Mock.Of<IMyClass>();
Mock.Get(mymock ).Setup(m => m.Method1(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(value: whatever);
```

And then somehow using this `mymock` with the line `s.TryAddTransient(IMyClass, ...` in the `ConfigureTestServices` code above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have the factory delegate return the mocked services when configuring the test server

```
var mymock = Mock.Of<IMyClass>();
Mock.Get(mymock)
    .Setup(m => m.Method1(It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns(value: whatever);

var webHostBuilder =
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("Testing")
        .UseContentRoot(projectDir)
        .ConfigureTestServices(services => {
            services.RemoveAll<IMyClass>();//Remove previous registration(s) of this service
            services.TryAddTransient<IMyClass>(sp => mymock);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

If you need a new mocked instance per call then move the logic into the factory delegate

Answer (score -4):

It's possible to build a service collection using mocks and feed that to your test server, but you should not. The test server is for doing integration tests, whereas mocks are for unit testing. You need to determine what kind of test you're doing, and choose one or the other.

Unit testing, as the name indicates, is concerned with testing one discrete unit of functionality. Mocks are a way to remove variables so you can ensure that one thing you're testing works or not.

Integration testing, on the other hand, is about testing a system top-down. You want to ensure that a given input results in a given output, *using everything in the system as it exists*. If you throw in mocks, then you're not testing anything, because you now don't know if it works or not simply because of the mock or the actual system is broken.

For example, let's say that you have a service that a particular action uses, which has a bug and will cause the action to throw an exception live. However, you replace it with a mock in your test server, which works fine. Your test passes, because the mock is working, but then when you push it live, everything breaks. Conversely, you could fail to mock the service correctly, and your test could fail even though the actual service is fine. Unless you test with your real system, you have no assurance of anything.

Comment: @chris_pratt, I got your point. Actually the need for moq arose, because for the integration test, we needed to use to in-memory DB instead of the real SQL DB, and it happens that one of the underlying methods is using a complex query not compatible with the in-memory DB, thus the idea to use moq to shortcut the underlying method. What would you recommend?

Comment: If a SUT is dependent on a particular DB provider, then your integration test should utilize such provider directly and not an in-memory database. The rest of your integration tests that aren't so dependent can continue to use the in-memory provider. If you mock the query, then the test is pointless anyways, so you might as well not even waste your time writing it.

Comment: In this particular test, the query itself is not of importance for the result. Plus testing on the real DB would need to handle resuming the DB to its previous state at the end of each test.

Comment: 1) If the query is not important for the result, then it shouldn't be part of the system in the first place. Not sure exactly what you're doing, but perhaps it would be better as part of a view component, for example. In either case, you should likely have some sort of fallback or catch, because if it truly doesn't matter, then failing for whatever reason should not take your system down with it. 2) If you're using the test server properly, you should be destroying and creating your in-memory database as part of the setup anyway, switching the provider doesn't change in anything in that case.

Comment: I meant "not of importance for the result [of this particular test]", not for the full system, come on. Still, thanks I appreciate your useful insights. However in some cases, we just need flexibility which is what TestServer brings on the table on top of unit-tests. Actually we opted for the TestServer because we were in need of testing a controller response coupled into a request for another controller. Do you think this could be done in in a pure unit-test approach without need for TestServer?